# Downloading bitmap image from URL in android not working

Tags: java, android

I am trying to download a image from url and converting it to Bitmap

The corresponding code is:

```
Bitmap pinbit=ImageDownloader.DownloadImage(URL_image+s.category+".png");
      pinbit=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(pinbit,75,56,false);
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(pinbit));
```

The class i used for downloading image is:

```
package com.igloo.classes;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class ImageDownloader {
    public static InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException
            {
                InputStream in = null;
                int response = -1;

                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))                   
                    throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

                try{
                    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                    httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                    httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                    httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    httpConn.connect();

                    response = httpConn.getResponseCode();               
                    if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        in = httpConn.getInputStream();                               
                    }                   
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new IOException("Error connecting");          
                }
                return in;   
            }
           public static Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL)
            {      
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                InputStream in = null;      
                try {
                    in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                return bitmap;              
            }
}
```

The code works on older devices like android 2.6 but when i ran on a new samsung tablet , the line:

```
Bitmap pinbit=ImageDownloader.DownloadImage(URL_image+s.category+".png");'
```

shows `NullPointerException`. Please help!

Comment: Did you ever debug the line? What is the value of `URL_image`, `s` and `s.category` ? Either one may be null.

Comment: yes,but they never returns null value.

Comment: Can we have the full logcat please.

Answer (score 0):

> Hey you can use the picasso library and add it to your project with it
>   you can download the image file from url in one line.

http://square.github.io/picasso/